# Browser crashes during automated test runs

Tags: selenium

For reliability testing, we are testing our web application through selenium automated tests runs on infinite loop on the Firefox /IE browser. Can some one have an idea on how to track when browser crashes/ hung up with out exiting/stopping the test run?

Comment: Have you tried running the test cases in the Selenium IDE? It shows at which position the test is at the moment - you can also turn down the speed of the test to debug it. It would also help if you provided how your test actually looks like which is causing the problem. Guess no one brought his magic ball here.

Answer (score 0):

i guess it could be done this way,

if the browser crashes : as there will not be any window opened, you will get an error

generated in javascript for further commands which you send and that will be sent to the

client code.

example :

try to close the window which is already closed or not existed and you will get an exception / error and catch this in the code. (java code example) :

```
try { 
    selenium.close(); //if it is a main window
} catch(SeleniumException se) { 
    if(!se.getMessage().equals("Current window or frame is closed!"))
        //do what ever you want here
}
```

as i said this is to give you some idea about how to go a head and may not be exactly what
you are looking for.

but i have a logic done in this way to close the entire application (multi window)

window by window and it works fine